# How do I add the Malayalam keyboard layout in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

I can't see a Malayalam keyboard layout in my Kubuntu 13.04's keyboard settings. The only Indian language available is Bengali. How can I update the available keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 2):

To add new keyboard layouts, go K-Menu --> System Settings --> Regional & Accessibility --> Keyboard Layout.
In the Layout tab, check the Enable Keyboard Layouts box. and choose the keyboard layout you want, and click Add.  Choose the appropriate Layout variant, and click on Apply to save your settings.

[image]

A flag icon should now appear in the system tray showing the current keyboard layout being used. Click the flag icon to switch to the other keyboard layout.

Comment: i cannot find my regional language in the list. is there any way to update the list?

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Open keyboard layouts and select + <kbd>add</kbd> button then from the list type as India and select what i have selected.

Hope that helps [image]

Comment: i cannot find malayalam in the list. the os i have is kubuntu. is there any way update the list with malayalam?

Comment: http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2008/05/13/installing-and-setting-up-malayalam-swanalekha-on-ubuntu-hardy-heron-8-04